# My site crashes when I import more than 1600 (roughly) posts to Wordpress, is there a DB limitation?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, database-design, import

I am using a CSV importer to import about 2500 Custom Posts to Wordpress. I have split up my large csv into 25 smaller files of 100 posts each so I don't run into time out issues.

When I reach file 16 it imports fine, meaning I have roughly around 1600 - 1800 Posts in the database.

However when I try and add the next batch of 100 my site stops working. (not the wordpress backend, but the frontend)

In Firebug I get "**Network Error 500 Internal Server Error**."

I have restored my DB a few times to the breaking point and tried adding different files to make sure my file was not corrupt and the same thing happened again and again.

I am not sure what is happening but my best guess is there must be some sort of limit on how many entries I can create in the DB or something I might be missing?

Anyone with any help on answering why this might be happening?

thanks

Comment: Could be that there is some issue with a particular post in that batch.  Try breaking the batch up into smaller chunks of say 20 to find the post that's causing the issue.

Comment: How do you import data? Using a web interface or database console?

Comment: Hi Toby, yeah I did try that...That is what I meant above with I restored the DB to the breaking point and then added a few more types of files. I have about 9 more and I tried 3 different ones which all gave the same result. I guess there is no limitation that you are aware of?

Comment: @Ertunç I use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/

Comment: If you have access to mysql console try importing using it (LOAD DATA INFILE command). Also try to check apache error logs. There maybe a clue indicating a limit or database error.

Comment: @Ertunç I actually did check the Apache logs and see this "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)" is there anything I can do to increase that?

Comment: @Redwall actually the error also states that it already has more then what you tried to allocate. It contradicts itself. However it indicates there is sth wrong. We should google for what the cause might be. If I find anything of use I'll respond.

Comment: Yeah man, I did find this thread but not sure what to make of it http://www.unix.com/web-programming/147642-solved-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-134217728-bytes-exhausted.html

Comment: First suggestion : if you have dedicated server locate your php.ini file and try increasing the following values _memory_limit :_ 
and _max_execution_time :_

Comment: Also check this link for Wordpress specific configuration [Wordpress memory limit](http://www.mytechopinion.com/2009/06/wordpress-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-error.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably hitting PHP timeout and memory limits on the host.

Increase `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` in php.ini and raise memory, too.

If you don't have access to the php.ini file, try these in .htaccess which *might* override php.ini, depending on the host server config. *But they may also throw a 500 error becuase of web host settings, so be ready to revert .htaccess*

```
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 120
memory_limit = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

You can also try raising PHP memory in wp-config.php with this line near the top of the file:

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

which may alow you to import without having to raise timeouts.

If none of these work, ask your host.

Comment: Hi Thanks...I don't actually see a php.ini file and I am trying to do this via htaccess and wp-config...I was trying `"php_flag max_execution_time 300 php_flag memory_limit "64M"` but that did not work. Gonna try what you suggest now to see if works..thanks

Comment: When I inserted your code into my htaccess I actually got a "Error occurred: 500 - internal server error" on the frontend of my site and nothing loaded :( I also tried wp-config but no luck there

Comment: 500 type errors means you can't add those kinds of directives due to host limits. Ask your host to raise memory/timeouts or find another webhost.

Comment: already submitted a ticket a few hours ago, but was trying to get this done myself rather than wait on their slow asses to get on it :) time for a beer I think...

Comment: Marked answer as correct as it is the right answer I am sure, I must be just limited by my server company with changing these things..thanks for help

Comment: @Redwall the comment stating 'find another webhost' might be better answer then. Hope my comments been useful.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add what worked for me. The code above from markratledge is right but just needed a few tweaks to actually work in the htaccess form.

I wrote it as follows

```
php_value max_execution_time 120
php_value max_input_time 120
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

basically removing the '=' and adding php_value